# How to calculate the resistance of a 3D shape?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electromagnetism, electrical-resistance

In the cube below with conductivity of c0, two electrodes as shown with copper color are attached to the bottom surface, and there is a voltage difference of V0 between the two electrodes. How can I calculate the effective resistance between two electrodes? How does the change in the shape of electrodes affect the resistance between them? Is it possible to define an effective area and effective length for this equation R = (1/c0) L/A

[image]

Comment: There is no simple formula to solve to this problem. See [Resistance of an object with arbitrary shape](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/467205) and [Calculating the resistance of a 3D shape between two points](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/190355).

Comment: Hello and welcome to the physics stack exchange! Since this is not a typical help site, it would be great to ask questions to benefit the wider audience. You could improve your post by **elaborating your question, explaining where you encounter the problem and what your progress is so far**.

Comment: You can refer to this link for more details : [How to ask homework type questions on this site](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/714/how-do-i-ask-homework-questions-on-physics-stack-exchange).
 In case you find these rules to be a bit harsh, you can always [go to any other suitable sites](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/391/my-question-was-closed-on-phys-se-can-you-recommend-me-another-internet-site-wh).

As someone said before, you can learn the alphabet from these sites and then come back here to ask questions about dinosaurs :)
Have a great time!